# Wrong working regular expression for parsing short terms

Tags: php, regex

I wrote some a regular expression for PHP to parsing abbreviation from string.

My code:

```
$re = "/(([$]?+[А-Яа-я.]+[.]){1,})/";
$str = "г. Братск, ж.р. Южный Падун, ул. Мамырская, 62А, за остановкой";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

And this script return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => г.
            [1] => ж.
            [2] => л.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => г.
            [1] => ж.
            [2] => л.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => г.
            [1] => ж.
            [2] => л.
        )

)
```

But it will work like this: 
`[1]=>'ж.р.', [2]=>'ул.'`
It means, that my regex parse part of abbreviation, though I need to get full abbreviation.

For example on regex101.com it pretty works: https://regex101.com/r/wQ7lR7/1

How I can get full abbreviation `('г.','ж.р.','ул.')`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the unicode modifier, `u`, http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php.

Example:

```
$re = "/(([$]?+[А-Яа-я.]+[.]){1,})/u";
$str = "г. Братск, ж.р. Южный Падун, ул. Мамырская, 62А, за остановкой";
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => г.
            [1] => ж.р.
            [2] => ул.
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => г.
            [1] => ж.р.
            [2] => ул.
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => г.
            [1] => ж.р.
            [2] => ул.
        )

)
```